# How can I upload videos without YouTube marking them as shorts?

Tags: youtube

My uploaded video is listed in YouTube "shorts." There's no explanation why and no setting to turn it off.  All the information I've found while searching the issue is focused on the mobile YouTube app.

I uploaded the video using YouTube's web application in Firefox. How can I upload *normal* videos without them being marked as shorts?

Answer (score 3):

If the video is under 1 minute, and meets either of the following criteria, YouTube will auto-classify it as a short.

1. The video is shot in square<sup>*****</sup> or vertical/portrait mode (eg. 1:1, 9:16, 3:4)
2. It has the #shorts in its title and description

This doesn't just apply to new videos. Older videos that are in vertical format and less than 60 seconds long also count as a YouTube Short and were transformed.

**Resources**
[YouTube Shorts Dimensions: How to Get the Right Size for Vertical Content](https://vidiq.com/blog/post/youtube-shorts-vertical-video/)

---

**<sup>*</sup>** This change (square video) started 2021-Oct when YouTube introduced shorts to desktop (previously mobile-only).